# Force.com Sites - Lookup Access Error for Guest Site User

Tags: visualforce, lookup, force.com-sites, guest-user

I have setup a Force.com Site with access to Visualforce page, however receive an error message when trying to use the Lookup fields on the page.

Some troubleshooting I've done so far:

1. Grant access to relevant VF pages
2. Grant access to relevant Objects/fields/record types of the Lookup relationship
3. Grant access to Site Standard Pages "Lookup Page"
4. Added my IP Addresses to "Network Access" IP ranges

Error:
[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the lookup object being referenced here? Does the (Guest) User has access to the record?

Comment: Yes - it's the Account object and the Guest user has access to the relevant fields/record type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had the same issue today, it was working fine before.

The issue got resolved : Added the 'Search Pages' under the Site Standard Pages section in Site Detail Page, and it worked.

Now there are 'Look Up Page' and 'Search Pages' under Site Standard section.

Salesforce Support tech helped us to resolve this.

[image: Screen Shot]